# How to generate random UUID using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I am newbie to xslt. i want to generate 32 digit long UUID using xslt and add it to the xml coming as an input. I tried to use the random function of math liberary but getting error.

**Input XML**

```
<users xmlns="ABC_Login">
   <email>ABC@gmail.com</email>
</users>
```

**XSLT Snippet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns1="ABC_Login"  xmlns:math="http://exslt.org/math"
extension-element-prefixes="math" version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="/ns1:users">
        <users>
            <email>
                <xsl:value-of select="ns1:email" />
            </email>
            <UUID>
                <xsl:value-of select="(floor(math:random()*10) mod 10) + 1" />
            </UUID>
        </users>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

i am using online editor but getting the exception as below. http://xslttest.appspot.com/

Error: Cannot find a matching 0-argument function named {http://exslt.org/math}random(). There is no Saxon extension function with the local name random

Actually i need to generate random token using xslt and add it in the input xml.

**Expected Output**

```
<users xmlns="ABC_Login">
       <email>ABC@gmail.com</email>
       <uuid>7B81A9B0D9-CA0E-E70F-ADFF-116EE7A1A980<</uuid>
    </users>
```

Can anybody help me in this regard. Best Regards,

Comment: Not all XSLT 1.0 processors implement all EXSLT extension functions. Which processor will you be using in actual production?

Comment: all you have in pure xslt-1.0 is 
`generate-id()`

Comment: Actually i want the expected output from the input xml while login. Is there any way to do it in xslt? Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you answer the question?

Comment: Sorry i made a mistake, i will be using XSLT 2.0 and saxon processor in actual production.

Comment: In what system are you processing the XML and XSL? For such things -- especially if you only need one and not many to be generated in one XSL process, I would generate it externally and pass it into the transform as a parameter.

Comment: You can implement this in pure XSLT 2 if you don't have extension functions or calls to java - there are lots of instructions in this topic, of which this is a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8126963/xslt-generate-uuid

Comment: @yamahito Your comment would be much more useful if it linked to a *specific* method.

Comment: Possibly, but I prefer to leave matters of taste to the reader ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason you are getting an error is that you are using an XSLT 2.0 processor (Saxon 9) which does not support the EXSLT math:random()) function.

Unfortunately, there is no native random() function in XSLT 2.0 either, but with Saxon you can call a Java method - for example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:math="java.lang.Math"
exclude-result-prefixes="math">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <output>
        <xsl:variable name="random" select="math:random()"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$random"/>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to generate a random number or:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:uuid="java.util.UUID"
exclude-result-prefixes="uuid">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <output>
        <xsl:variable name="random" select="uuid:randomUUID()"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$random"/>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to generate a [random UUID](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html)

Comment: Unfortunately this is not possible with Saxon-HE.

Comment: But you can implement UUID yourself in XSLT 2: see the link in my comment on the question, above.